# Declared array of size [x][y] and another array with size [y-1]

Tags: c, arrays

I am using Code::Blocks 10.05, and the GNU GCC Compiler.

Basically, I ran into a really strange (and for me, inexplicable) issue that arises when trying to initialize an array outside it's declared size. In words, it's this:

> *There is a declared array of size [x][y].
>
> *There is another declared array with size [y-1].

The issue comes up when trying to put values into this second, `size [y-1]` array, outside of the `[y-1]` size. When this is attempted, the first array `[x][y]` will no longer maintain all of its values. I simply don't understand why breaking (or attempting to break) one array would affect the contents of the other. Here is some sample code to see it happening (it is in the broken format. To see the issue vanish, simply change `array2[4]` to `array2[5]` (thus eliminating what I have pinpointed to be the problem).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    //Declare the array/indices
    char array[10][5];
    int array2[4]; //to see it work (and verify the issue), change 4 to 5
    int i, j;

    //Set up use of an input text file to fill the array
    FILE *ifp;
        ifp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    //Fill the array
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
        {
            fscanf(ifp, "%c", &array[i][j]);
            //printf("[%d][%d] = %c\n", i, j, array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (j = 4; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            printf("[%d][%d] = %c\n", i, j, array[i][j]);
        }
        //PROBLEM LINE*************
        array2[j] = 5;

    }

    fclose(ifp);
    return 0;

}
```

So does anyone know how or why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you write outside of an array bounds, C lets you.  You're just writing to somewhere else in the program.

C is known as the lowest level high level language.  To understand what "low level" means, remember that each of these variables you have created you can think of as living in physical memory.  An array of integers of length 16 might occupy 64 bytes if integers are size 4.  Perhaps they occupy bytes 100-163 (unlikely but I'm not going to make up realistic numbers, also these are usually better thought of in hexadecimal).  What occupies byte 164?  Maybe another variable in your program.  What happens if you write to one past your array of 16 integers?  well, it might write to that byte.

C lets you do this.  Why?  If you can't think of any answers, then maybe you should switch languages.  I'm not being pedantic - if this *doesn't* benefit you then you might want to program in a language in which it is a little harder for you to make weird mistakes like this.  But reasons include:

- It's faster and smaller.  Adding bounds checking takes time and space, so if you're writing code for a microprocessor, or writing a JIT compiler, speed and size really do matter a lot.
- If you want to understand machine architecture and go into hardware, e.g. if you're a student, it's a good gateway from programming into OS/hardware/electrical engineering.  And much of computer science.
- Being close to machine code, it's standard in a way that many other languages and systems have to, or can easily, support some degree of compatibility with.
- Other reasons that I would be able to give if I ever actually had to work this close to the machine code.

The moral is:  In C, be very careful.  You must check your own array bounds.  You must clean up your own memory.  If you don't, your program often won't crash but will start just doing really weird things without telling you where or why.

Answer (score 2):

```
  for (j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
```

should be

```
  for (j = 0; j <= 4; j++)
```

and `array2` max index is `3` so

```
  array2[j] = 5;
```

is also going to be a problem when `j == 4`.

C array indexes start from `0`. So an `[X]` array valid indexes are from `0` to `X-1`, thus you get X elements in total.

You should use the `<` operator, instead of `<=`, in order to show the same number in both the array declaration `[X]` and in the expression `< X`. For instance

```
  int array[10];
  ...
  for (i=0 ; i < 10 ; ++i) ... // instead of `<= 9`
```

This is less error prone.

Answer (score 1):

If you're outside the bounds of one array, there's always a possibility you'll be inside the bounds of the other.

Answer (score 1):

`array2[j] = 5;` - This is your problem of overflow.

`for (j = 0; j <= 5; j++)` - This is also a problem of overflow. Here also you are trying to access 5th index, where you can access only 0th to 4th index.

In the process memory, while calling each function one activation records will be created to keep all the local variables of the function and also it will have some more memory to store the called function address location also. In your function four local variables are there, `array`, `array2`, `i` and `j`. All these four will be aligned in an order. So if overflow happens it will first tries to overwrite in the variable declared above or below which depends on architecture. If overflow happens for more bytes then it may corrupt the entire stack itself by overwriting some of the local variables of the called functions. This may leads to crash also, Sometimes it may not but it will behave indifferently as you are facing now.